# If a group $G$ is $(2,3,t)$-generated, then $G$ is a factor of the modular group which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 * \mathbb{Z}_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-product

If a group $G$ is $(2,3,t)$-generated, where $t$ is an odd divisor of $|G|$ then $G$ is a factor of the modular group which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 * \mathbb{Z}_3$.

From assumptions, let $x$ and $y$ be the only two generators of $G$. Then $|x|=2$, $|y|=3$, $|xy|=t$. I believe the definition of "factor" here is the same as that of a subgroup.

But can you explain intuitively why $G$ is a factor of $PSL(2, \mathbb{Z})?$

Comment: Well, you have to tell us what *you* mean by factor, although I'll say that I've never heard that a "factor" of a group is synonymous with a subgroup. Where did this problem come from?

Comment: I think you are confusing factors (subgroups) and quotients.

Comment: Are you asking about an explicit isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_2 \mathbin{*} \mathbb{Z}_3 \cong \operatorname{PSL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Can you explain further?

Comment: @SammyBlack I think I want to know why or how $G$ is a factor of the free product of two groups of order 2 and 3.

Comment: Consider the (2,3,5) finite group, it is not a subgroup but a quotient of $Z_2*Z_3$. Which country are you in? In some places, "factor" is used for a quotient but not in the US.

Comment: @MoisheKohan "Factor group" is synonymous with "quotient group" - see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_group) for example. I had no idea that this  country dependent.

Comment: To answer the question, if $G$ is any group whatsoever with elements $x$ and $y$ of orders $2$ and $3$, then there is a homomophism $Z_2*Z_3 \to G$ mapping the generators of $Z_2$ and $Z_3$ to $x$ and $y$. That is called the universality property of the free product.